# Dash icons didn't change when upgrading to 13.04

Tags: unity, upgrade, 13.04, icons

I've recently updated from 12.10 to 13.04, and everything is working fine but the icons at the bottom of the dash didn't change. Instead of the new ones shown in [this link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/12/new-dash-icons-proposed-for-ubuntu-13-04), I'm still getting the ones from Ubuntu 12.10.

Tried `unity --reset-icons` and `setsid unity`, but neither of them helped.

Comment: you tried FS- collection?

Comment: I know i can add new icons but I didn't want to change it, that's why i asked for help, to set tp 13.04 default and not 12.10 or new icons.

Comment: Did you make a clean install or upgraded directly from 12.10 ? I'm guessing you made an upgrade from 12.10. I'm not sure what happens with icons if you make an upgrade rather than a clean install, perhaps the new icons were not overwritten. Try searching for the 13.04 icons and install them from Advanced Settings

Comment: Yes, I upgraded from 12.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download it, Extract it and copy it on /usr/share/unity/icons/

[Unity 6 Icons](http://ubuntuone.com/1dAJ392ASRDPZ5Ib2ep2q8) The official Unity icons 13.04

```
  cd Downloads  # assuming that you have downloaded it in Downloads folder
  tar zxpf 6.tar.gz
  sudo cp -r 6/* /usr/share/unity/icons/
```

Then Restart

---

**Reverting the changes**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-common
```

> It will reset the dash icons

[Source Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/get-ubuntu-touch-feeling-on-unity.html) Section **Reverting the changes**

Comment: This one didn't work also

Comment: lots of people having issue with upgrade ...the only solution is to clean installation ... or you can try new icons http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/get-ubuntu-touch-feeling-on-unity.html ...

Comment: ok lets try new icons and then ... sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-common
 may be this will .... give icons last chance before clean installation

Comment: same problem, nothing happens

Comment: @Danilo updated the answer...try this .....

Comment: Now you talking, it's working fine now. Just changed the icons, updated (AT+F2 => unity) and restored default and it's ok now

Comment: thats good to know finally it worked .....

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the Home Folder app is displaying a picture of a folder instead of the new File chest. I haven't tried this myself, since I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04, so I'm not sure that this will work.

The launcher used to start the Home Folder app (Nautilus) is different in Ubuntu 13.04 compared to older versions. Before, the launcher was called "Home Folder", although a "Files" launcher also existed that ran the same app. However, in 13.04, the one pinned to the launcher is the "Files" one.

So the Home Folder is probably displaying the icon it says it is - the home folder. Try searching the Dash for "Files" and pin it to your Launcher instead of the "Home Folder" launcher.

Here is a picture of how the icons look in Ubuntu 13.04:

[image]

Comment: YES, I'm talking about the home folder icons and NO that didn't work either. The only icon that changed for me is the home folder icon, the other in the home folder (Music, pictures, etc) still old looking

Comment: @Danilo can you edit you quesiton to include a picture of what is wrong and maybe a link to what you want? In Ubuntu 13.04, the only icons that changed are the Files, Software Center, and Software Updater icons. The actual folder icons are still the same.

Comment: @Danilo I've added a picture of Ubuntu 13.04, is this what you see, or is something still wrong?

Comment: Sorry dash icons not home

Comment: Sorry I've mistaken the names it was dash icons has you can see for  on this [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/12/new-dash-icons-proposed-for-ubuntu-13-04) the only icons that had changed for me was software center and home folder icons the remaining changed the same acording to the picture, but now is ok. sorry for my english by the way

Comment: @Danilo That's all right, I'll edit your question to use the correct name and to include a picture for future reference for people having the same problem.